# Missing Argument Parameter #1 in Call for an expression with no parameters

Tags: ios, class, swiftui, parameter-passing, instance

I keep getting an error "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" when i try to call a ForEach on a list of Workouts, and I don't know what Swift is confused about. I believe it has something to do with which ViewModel it is referencing, but im not sure how to explicitly tell it.

Here's my code of my View:

```
struct WorkoutProgramView: View {
    @ObservedObject var workoutViewModel: WorkoutViewModel
    @StateObject var vm: WorkoutListViewModel = .init()
    @State var currentWeek: [Date] = []
    @State var currentDay: Date = Date()
    @State var selection: String? = nil
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150, maximum: 400))]

var body: some View {

ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns){
                    ForEach(vm.workoutDays, id:\.id) { day in
                        if isSameDay(date1: currentDay, date2: day.date!){
                            ZStack{
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).frame(width: .infinity).padding().foregroundColor(Color.black).opacity(0.1)
}
```

I get the error on the ForEach row.

Here's my workoutViewModel and vm:

```
import SwiftUI
@MainActor
class WorkoutListViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @ObservedObject var workoutViewModel = WorkoutViewModel()
    @Published var workoutDays: [WorkoutDays] = []
    
    func loadWorkoutData() async throws{
        let svc = NestedFirestoreService(workoutViewModel: workoutViewModel)

        self.workoutDays = try await svc.retrieveWorkoutDays()
    }
}


class WorkoutViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var date: Date = Date()
    @Published var exercise: Double = 0.0
    @Published var workoutProgramList: [WorkoutProgramModel] = []
    @Published var todaysFoodList: [FoodItem] = []
    @Published var workoutProgramSelected: String = ""
    @Published var workoutDayData: [WorkoutDays] = []
    @Published var workoutDaySelected: String = ""
    @Published var exerciseData: [ExerciseModel] = []
    @Published var ExerciseSelected: String = ""
    @Published var loggedSet: Int = 0
    @Published var loggedReps: Int = 0
    @Published var loggedWeight: Int = 0
    @Published var notes: String = ""
    @Published var dayAndExerciseList: [newStrengthModel] = []
}
```

And here's my WorkoutDays model":

```
struct WorkoutDays: Encodable, Decodable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var date: Date?
    var description: String?
    var timeToCompleteWarmup: Double?
    var timeToCompleteStrength: Double?
    var timeToCompleteMetcon: Double?
    var timeToCompleteAccessories: Double?
    var exercises: [ExerciseModel]?
}
```

```
struct ExerciseModel: Encodable, Decodable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var workoutDayID: String?
    var name: String?
    var reps: [Int]?
    var percent: [Double]?
    var linkToVideo: String?
    var isCompleted: Bool?
    var description: String?
    var timeToComplete: Double?
    var type: String? 
}
```

Can anyone help out? Been stuck on this for days and its definitely bugging me lol.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: By the way, unrelated to you issue, but nested `ObservableObject`s are not really supported in SwiftUI. Also, you shouldn't be using `@ObservedObject` *within* a `class` -- that property wrapper is for use with a `View`

Comment: I suspect the issue is caused by the **optional** property wrapper `@DocumentID`.

Comment: @jnpdx on the "ForEach" line

Comment: @vadian , why do you think this is the problem and do you have any ideas how to fix?

Comment: The `id` parameter of `ForEach` expects a non-optional KeyPath value.  You have to use something else unique.